# Kernel trick of dot products

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I am trying to understand the kernel trick in Support Vector Machines. The things I don't get.

1. Why is ($\sum_{i}^{n}x_iz_i$)($\sum_{j}^{n}x_jz_j$) equal to 
   $\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n}x_ix_jz_iz_j$?
2. And why is $\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n}x_ix_jz_iz_j$ equal to  $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(x_ix_j)(z_iz_j)$?

Reference: Pg 15 http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Comment: In *what*? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DonAntonio Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: What is "SVMs" ? Non-standard short writings do a lot of problems here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Added, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both statements follow from the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of addition and multiplication.
$$(\sum_i^n x_i z_i)(\sum_j^n x_j z_j)=\sum_i^n (x_i z_i \sum_j^n x_j z_j)\\
=\sum_i^n (\sum_j^n x_i z_i x_j z_j)=\sum_i^n \sum_j^n x_i z_i x_j z_j$$

In the second statement, $\sum_{i,j=1}^n$ is simply shorthand for $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you write more steps to make it clear. I am not sure how you are applying th distributive property here.

Comment: Do you understand what the $\sum$ symbol means? This is not harder than $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$